# Variable Component Configurations in web2py DAL

Tags: python, web2py

I have some components which themselves have some settings. I want to be able to configure each component for a specific consumer (which needs to call the component with defined settings + values). I want to use the SQLFORM.smartgrid for adding a component to a consumer + settings. I've tried many approaches, some of them were successful, however the problem there was that it was possible to add components with settings not belonging to this specific component. Meaning, I were able to choose in the dropdowns every setting from the settings table combined with every component.

Here is some sample table (MySQL) to illustrate this:

[image]

Is this the correct form (from a DB design perspective too) to achieve this? How should one implement this in web2py?

EDIT: Here is some sample DB model code for the screenshot:

```
db.define_table(
    'Components',
        Field(
            'component_id',
            type = 'id'
        ),
        Field(
            'name',
            type = 'string'
        ),
        format = '%(name)s',
)

#--------
db.define_table(
    'ComponentSettings',
        Field(
            'componentsetting_id',
            type = 'id'
        ),
        Field(
            'component_id',
            db.Components
        ),
        Field(
            'name',
            type = 'string'
        ),
        format = '%(name)s',
)

#--------
db.define_table(
    'ComponentConsumers',
        Field(
            'componentconsumer_id',
            type = 'id'
        ),
        Field(
            'component_id',
            db.Components
        ),
        Field(
            'name',
            type = 'string'
        ),
        format = '%(name)s',
)

#--------
db.define_table(
    'ComponentSettingValues',
        Field(
            'componentsettingvalue_id',
            type = 'id'
        ),
        Field(
            'componentsetting_id',
            db.ComponentSettings
        ),
        Field(
            'component_id',
            db.Components
        ),
        Field(
            'componentconsumer_id',
            db.ComponentConsumers
        ),
        Field(
            'componentsetting_value',
            type = 'string'
        ),
        format = '%(componentsetting_value)s',
)
```

Here you can see the problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the call to `SQLFORM.smartgrid(...)` ?

Comment: Sure,
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(
        db.ComponentConsumers,
        linked_tables = [
            'ComponentSettingValues',
            'Components',
            'ComponentSettings'
        ],
        maxtextlength = 50,
        divider = ' > ',
        details = False,
        csv = False,
        searchable = True,
        deletable = True,
        editable = True,
        create = True
    )
Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? Would be really appreciated...